# 'sed' usage in perl script error

Tags: perl, sed

I have the following line in a Perl script:

```
my $temp = `sed 's/ /\n/g' /sys/bus/w1/devices/w1_bus_master1/10-000802415bef/w1_slave | grep t= | sed 's/t=//'`;
```

Which throws up the error: 
"sed: -e expression #1, char 2: unterminated `s' command"

If I run a shell script as below it works fine:

```
temp1=`sed 's/ /\n/g' /sys/bus/w1/devices/w1_bus_master1/10-000802415bef/w1_slave | grep t= | sed 's/t=//'`
echo $temp1
```

Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to SO. =) Why are you doing that with sed from a Perl script, anyway? You could do it in Perl as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perl interpretes your `\n` as a literal newline character. Your command line will therefore look something like this from sed's perspective:

```
sed s/ /
/g ...
```

which sed doesn't like. The shell does not interpret it that way.

The proper solution is not to use sed/grep in such a situation at all. Perl is, after all, very, very good at handling text. For example (untested):

```
use File::Slurp;
my @lines = split m/\n/, map { s/ /\n/g; $_ } scalar(read_file("/sys/bus...));
@lines    = map { s/t=//; $_ } grep { m/t=/ } @lines;
```

Alternatively escape the `\n` once, e.g. `sed 's/ /\\n/g'...`.

Comment: Moritz, many thanks for the reply. Unfortunately I have little knowledge of Perl (I'm butchering an existing script) hence why I used the above. Your second solution works great and I will see if I can get the first working too.

Comment: Fair enough :) That's why I gave the second solution in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the `\n` in our first regular expression. The backtick-operator in perl thinks it is a control-character and inserts a newline instead of the string `\n`.

```
                     |
                     V
my $temp = `sed 's/ /\\n/g' /sys/bus/ # ...
```